# Make thread run on non EDT (event dispatch thread) thread from EDT

Tags: java, swing, awt, event-dispatch-thread

I have a method running on the EDT and within that I want to make it execute something on a new (non EDT) thread. My current code is follows:

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
//gathering parameters from GUI

//below code I want to run in new Thread and then kill this thread/(close the JFrame)
new GameInitializer(userName, player, Constants.BLIND_STRUCTURE_FILES.get(blindStructure), handState);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create and start a new Java Thread that executes your method from within the EDT thread :

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        Thread t = new Thread("my non EDT thread") {
            public void run() {
                //my work
                new GameInitializer(userName, player, Constants.BLIND_STRUCTURE_FILES.get(blindStructure), handState);
            }

        };
        t.start();
    }
```

Comment: Look at my example, the work would not be executed on the EDT.

Comment: Thanks I called t.run() instead which made it break

Comment: Why no `@Override` on `run`, or better why not use `Runnable`?

Comment: I'm not here to spoon feed - both of those are great ideas.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `SwingWorker` to undertake a task on a worker thread off the EDT.

E.g.

```
class BackgroundTask extends SwingWorker<String, Object> {
    @Override
    public String doInBackground() {
        return someTimeConsumingMethod();
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Then wherever you call it:

```
(new BackgroundTask()).execute();
```